# What are the differences between different versions of Angry Birds Space?

Tags: angry-birds

I own both an Android phone and a tablet and I am trying to figure out what the differences are between these Angry Birds Space versions:

- Angry Birds Space
- Angry Birds Space Premium
- Angry Birds Space HD

One is free and the other two are paid apps, but looking at the description they seem to have the same content and features. Can someone clarify the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both premium and HD are ad-free and the latter is for tablets.

Comment: But if I buy the HD version can I have the ad-free version also on my phone? Or do I have to buy both?

Comment: @Drake I think you have to buy both.

Comment: The HD version doesn't show up on phones at least not for me.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to install Angry Birds Space on my tablet. It has in-game ads as expected, but its graphics seems native (1280x800) and not stretched. I am wondering now what are really the differences between Angry Birds Space HD and Angry Birds Space Premium to justify the big cost difference.

Comment: There seems to be a little uproar on Amazon support because Fire users can only install HD but apparently they can't notice any difference between the two versions either.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the HD version in the Google Play Store on my Motorola Xoom tablet. I have discovered that there is virtually no difference really, and definitely not worth the $2.98. Feel free to check it out for yourself, because unlike iOS, Android has the option to refund your purchase within 15 minutes, I believe, of the time of purchase. I refunded mine because the only differences I could find were that the start-up screen after the white "Rovio" screen was not stretched (but every other screen/level I tried was), and also when you are in a level or at the start-up screen where you press "Play", the pause buttons are slightly larger.

I also believe it is pointless to purchase the Premium version on either a tablet or phone, because the only difference is that it is ad-free, to my knowledge. A helpful little tip that Rovio doesn't want anyone to know is that the ads the put in the free version require some form of internet connection to be generated in the game. So to solve this, you could just put your phone/tablet on Airplane Mode if you want since it's simpler, but all you really have to do is disable the WiFi AND data services on your smartphone, and boom - no ads. Obviously, on your tablet (assuming you don't have 3G/4G) all you have to do is disable WiFi. I actually have widgets from HD Widgets (which I highly recommend and is well worth the $1.99) that allows you to disable both data services and WiFi with the tap of a button. And there you go, you've just saved a dollar. Or three.

Hope this helps and clears things up for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Play store will let you know which devices each one is compatible with.  The Premium was compatible with all my phone-sized devices.

Note that there is also one that is tuned for the Kindle Fire called Angry Birds Space HD (Kindle Fire Edition) in the Amazon Appstore.

Comment: The HD is also available in the play store, so it's not Fire specific.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on my tablet when I downloaded the regular free version that is doesn't have those danger missions, but it does on the phone for all Samsung users apparently. On iOS i believe it is an in-app purchase. Check out:

http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-space-now-available/